# How many empty sets are there?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Thre are many sets with a single object, for example the set which only contains the statue of liberty or the set which contains my copy of Catch-22.

But how many sets are there that contain nothing?

On the face of it there seems to be just the one. The empty set is unique in its particularity as it contains nothing to distinguish itself.

On the other hand one could say that there are many empty sets, and that they are all identical - as in isomorphic - but not identical - as in they are exactly the same. To make this more concrete, consider Jamila & Jemima each carrying a basket, and in Jamilas basket there is an emerald, and in Jemimas basket there is a ruby. So the contents of their baskets are not identical. If they empty out their baskets. The contents of the basket are now identical (isomorphic) but the two baskets are not identical.

Which is the more accurate view?

Is it correct to say in formalised ZFC that there is just one empty set?

Is it correct to say that in the categorical set theory, say ETCS, that there are many empty sets but they are all isomorphic?

I am less interested in the 'formal' parts of the question as opposed to the conceptual arguments about uniqueness or non-uniqueness of empty 'sets' - where sets shouldn't be thought of as in ZFC

It does turn out that in ETCS there are more than one empty set (and since they are intial) they are also all isomorphic to each other. See the anser to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567403/etcs-set-theory-are-empty-sets-isomorphic)

Comment: There is exactly one empty set according to the most usual axiomatization of set theory (viz. ZFC). That there is one is guaranteed by the Empty Set Axiom. That it is unique is guaranteed by the Extensionality Axiom.

Comment: I am not sure if it is quite right to say that their IS more than one empty set in ETCS. My impression is that their COULD be more than one empty set, but it COULD also be unique. I may be misunderstanding something however.

Comment: In **ETCS** you have an **initial object** that plays the role of an **empty set**. Because the definition is based on a universal property (for any object A there is exactly one morphism from the initial object to A), an initial object is unique up to isomorphism. Since in category theory you are anyway interested to uniqueness up to isomorphism, you speak of *the initial object*.

Comment: ..though it is correct that in a concrete structure (world / interpretation / model) there might be several initial objects, however all guaranteed to be isomorphic.

Comment: You don't need to think of an *initial object* as something *empty* - it can be anything, that fulfills the defining property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81980/discussion-between-jobermark-and-mozibur-ullah).

Answer (score 14):

In ZFC we have two axioms that settle that question:

> **Empty Set**. There is a set that contains nothing.
>
> **Extensionality**. If sets A and B have exactly the same members, then A = B.

The Empty Set Axiom allows us to conclude that there is an empty set. Suppose there are two empty sets A and B. Vacuously, every member of A is a member of B (since A has no members), and vice versa. Therefore by the Axiom of Extensionality it follows that A and B are the same set. These axioms (existence and extensionality) thereby guarantee that there is exactly one empty set (usually denoted by '∅').

I'm not at all familiar with ETCS, so I won't comment on that part of the question.

---

Mozibur has already given a satisfying answer to the conceptual question, so I'll quote:

> The empty set is unique in its particularity as it contains nothing to distinguish itself.

Since ZFC distinguishes sets by their contents, any two empty sets will be indistinguishable because neither can contain anything that the other doesn't. In the baskets analogy, since the two empty baskets have different locations we want to say that they are two distinct empty baskets. But since for ZFC sets are not located in space-time, the two baskets are identical because it cannot, in the language of ZFC, be said something true about one that's false about the other.

Extensionality, in ZFC, trims the universe by identifying any two things that have the same members, allowing us to unambiguously name such things as the empty set ∅, the intersection of two sets A ∩ B, the ordered pair of two sets (A,B), and so on. In a universe with many empty sets, the definition of '∅' would get more complicated because we would have to identify it with the class of all empty sets, and that complication would crawl all the way up the definitional hierarchy.

Comment: Ok - great, that deals with the question in the framework of ZFC? What about about the conceptual question? Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: My response turned out to be pretty long, so I've added it to the post instead.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Conceptually speaking, you could create a system with distinguishable empty sets, but it wouldn't be ZFC any more.  The big question would be what would you gain from making that shift.

Comment: What is the meaning of the phrase "conceptual question" distinct from ZFC or any other particular formalization of set theory? How do we know your concept of an empty set is the same as mine? That's why we have formalizations, right? Absent any formalization, the question's meaningless. It's like asking if you see the same color orange as I do.

Comment: I think it's a meaningful question. The assumption is that there are some pre-theoretical intuitions that we have about certain objects (e.g. ordered pairs). Then, when we variously explicate (e.g. construct, axiomatize, etc.) those objects (e.g. using Wiener's or Kuratowski's definitions, etc.), we check against this intuitive basis to see if we've captured all that we consider relevant about those things (e.g. that if <a,b> = <x,y> then a=x and b=y, etc.). That's why I think it's very important to be very clear about the intuitions that we have about things even before we formalize them.

Comment: Which Kuratowskis or Weiners definitions? Are these for Set theory?

Comment: For ordered pairs. Kuratowski's is the standard one: <a,b> = {{a}, {a,b}}. Wiener's was first, but didn't become popular; it was: <a,b> = {{{x}, &empty;}, {{y}}}. (Enderton 1977:36).

Comment: Interesting. Does this also mean that multiple sets cannot exist which contain the same element and nothing else? So for example, there can't be 2 sets A{a} and B{a}?

Comment: @FedericoRazzoli Exactly. 'A' and 'B' are different names for the same set; and the extensionality axiom says why we consider them identical.

Comment: @Hunan Rostomyan: "In a universe with many empty sets, the definition of '&empty;' would get more complicated because we would have to identify it with the class of all empty sets" - alternatively (without extensionality) one could show, that the choice of a particular empty set doesn't matter and work with any of them.

Comment: @FWE good point. Thanks very much for the edit.

Answer (score 5):

The answers above give you the *mathematical* reason within ZFC for the *uniqueness* and *existence* of the *empty set*.

For this from an intuitive point of view, you can use the analogy with a *box*.

A set is **not** a box, but the *content* of the box.

So, you can have two different empty boxes, but their content is the same : the "empty content".

Comment: A set _is_ a box, for example: the empty set is the empty box (we call it "{}"); it contains nothing. If two boxes contain nothing, they're still different boxes, because, for example, you can use one to store your old books in it, and you can burn the other one. If two sets both contain nothing, you cannot "do" anything with one that you won't simultaneously be doing with the other.

Comment: A set is **not** a box; it is the *content* of the box.

Comment: I guess we don't have to agree about that point. What did you think about the rest of my comment?

Comment: @HunanRostomyan I think your argument supports Mauro's point — two empty boxes might be different, but the _contents_ of two empty boxes are the same.  Also, unlike physical boxes, sets are "immutable" — if you "do" anything to a set, you get a different set.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan - Two boxes (also when empty) are different things : the set-box is an analogy, so is not easy to try to find perfect correspondence between sets an physical thing. In set theory the empty set 0 is different from {0}; the first is empty, the second not: it has exactly *one* element (the empty set).

Comment: Yes, an empty box is not the same as a box with an empty box in it. But that has nothing to do with my question. Anyway, we don't have to discuss it. In general, I'm open to the idea of distinguishing empty sets, I just can't think of any good mathematical reason for doing it. Consider an axiomatization of set theory without extensionality. What reason could one have to prefer that over the extensional ones...

Comment: @HunanRostomyan  You might be interested in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63910/example-of-a-model-in-set-theory-where-the-axiom-of-extensionality-does-not-hold

Comment: Thanks very much for the link. Skimmed through the answers; looks great. I think the link is worth adding as a comment to the main question; I'm sure others would be interested in the discussion also.

Comment: An intuition of an empty set being a representative of *nothing* (the empty content of a box) might lead into a wrong direction. Empty sets are rather base objects of your theory in so far as they don't contain further objects inside of them. Requiring or not that all empty sets shall be identical makes the difference between working in a universe with (1) just one base object (the one empty set) or (2) possible many base objects (empty sets).

Answer (score 4):

There is only one empty set.

Two sets are considered as different by ZFC if one contains an element not within the other. This comes from the extensionality axiom of ZF.

Answer (score 4):

Since the mathematical point has been made above, I'll just comment on the ontological side:  One could ask the same question about everything, from the number 1 to human beings.  Is there just the one number 1, or are there many isomorphic mathematical objects with its properties?  Is there just one me, or are there many other isomorphic (upon some agreement of which physical objects are isomorphic) me's?

Since I doubt that one can come up with a reason for having a multiplicity of such objects (except possibly when talking about modal identity), it is probably best to have just one such object in one's ontology.

Comment: This is a good point - in fact, Frege specifically argued to the effect that there is just one number 1, and that this need to categorically define the number 1 (and other mathematical objects) was what led him to his use of Hume's Principle as a key defining axiom for his formalization of second order arithmetic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hume's_principle .  Of course, as we now know, the same strategy struggled with BL5 and set theory...

Comment: @Addem I don not agree. An empty set might just be seen as a base object of your universe. A manyfold of empty sets (in the sense of things, that do not contain themselves other things) might therefore come up quite naturally (see e.g. the example of the sets of cars below).

Answer (score 2):

> **Question 1.** Is it correct to say in formalised ZFC that there is just one empty set?

**ZFC** requires a unique empty set, i.e. for ZFC there is just one empty set. This is due to the **Extensionality** axiom of ZFC, which identifies two sets whenever they have the same elements - formally:

∀ x ∀ y [∀ z [z ∈ x ↔ z ∈ y] → x = y]

and the **Null Set** axiom, which requires the existence of an empty set (i.e. a set containing no other set) - formally:

∃ x ∀ y [y ∉ x]

**References.**

[Wikipedia.Axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality)

[nLab.Axiom of extensionality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/axiom+of+extensionality)

[nLab.ZFC](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ZFC#axioms)

---

> **Question 2.** Is it correct to say that in the categorical set theory, say ETCS, that there are many empty sets but they are all isomorphic?

**ETCS** requires at least one and allows several *initial objects* alias *empty sets*. This is because an *initial object* 0 (that can be thought of as representing an empty set) is defined by a **universal property**, namely that for any object x there is exactly one mormhism from 0 to x - formally:

∀ x ∃! 0 → x

(the arrow here is a morphism, not a deduction) and is thus defined up to (unique) isomorphism. However since the *initial objects* are isomorphic one speaks of *the* initial object.

**Two initial objects 0 and 0' must be isomorphic:** since 0 is initial it exists 0 → 0', and since 0' is initial it exists 0' → 0. Then the composition 0 → 0' → 0 must be the identity on 0 (since 0 is initial, there can by definition just be one mormhism 0 → 0 but this has to be the identity, which is given in any category for any object). Analogue argumentation shows that 0' → 0 → 0' must be the identity on 0'. So 0 and 0' are isomorphic (what we just showed is the definition of two objects being isomorphic: a and b are isomorphic if there are two morphisms f: a → b and g: b → a and gf = id: a → a and fg = id: b → b.

**References.**

[Wikipedia.Initial and terminal objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects#Properties)

[nLab.Initial object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/initial+object)

[nLab.ETCS](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS)

---

**Example (Sets of cars).**
If you would regard sets of cars, then any car, that is not containing other cars (so excluded loaded car transporters or cars with matchbox cars inside), is an empty set. ZFC regards all those cars as identical - thus there is only one car that is not containing other cars. ETCS allows to distinguish them, but regards them as isomorphic.

---

> **Question *.** Which is the more accurate view?

**My personal opinion.** Asking for accuracy is perhaps not the right approach here. One could instead ask which concept to work with. This depends on your criteria:

(1) In case you are interested in the study of well-orders and the cumulative hierarchy, you might want to work with ZFC.

(2) In case you are interested in mathematics apart from that and how sets are used there, you should probably have a look at category theory and ETCS rather than ZFC.

**References.**

[nLab.Cumulative hierarchy](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cumulative+hierarchy)

[Leinster.Rethinking set theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.6543.pdf)

Comment: +1 Good answer. If you added references for the extensionality axiom of ZFC and for more information on the isomorphism in ETCS this would improve the answer because it would give the reader a place to go for more information. This would also make the answer not an opinion but a reporting of what others claim.